# Integrating Wordpress Authorization and Sign in with Android

Tags: android, wordpress, rest, jwt

I am trying to build a native Android app for the Wordpress site. I am making use of WP REST API v2 (https://wordpress.org/plugins/rest-api/) to fetch the posts and other required attributes. I require authenticating the user, for which i have used JWT Authentication for WP REST API (https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)
API to Generate and Validate token works fine. However when i try to pass the generated token in the header i keep getting the below error.

```
{
    "code": "jwt_auth_bad_config",
    "message": "JWT is not configurated properly, please contact the admin",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

Any suggestions as to what is going wrong? Requesting help to get this thing running.

Comment: I added this plugin and every things seems fine. I can get token. But REST request works without any authorization just like before. why it can not restricts apis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TL;DR;
Move the definition of `JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY` to the top of your `wp-config.php` file

Detailed solution :

As stated in the installation doc of the plugin, 
the JWT needs a secret key to sign the token this secret key must be unique and never revealed.

Thus, you must add this line into your wp-config.php file

```
define('JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY', 'your-top-secrect-key');
```

However, what the doc does not say, is that **you should not put this at the end of the file**. 
Insert this line just after the other definitions (AUTH_KEY, SECURE_AUTH_KEY, ... NONCE_SALT), and the 403 error should be gone.

I guess that's because the definition of `JWT_AUTH_SECRET_KEY` must be done before require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');

Comment: I added this plugin and everything seems fine and I can get Token and request with token and if it is invalid i will get the error.. BUT i can call all apis even without Authentication header  and they works fine. why? why plugin do not restrict all requests?

Comment: This is not a comment, this is another question. You should create a new question for this one.